# Datagrid ComboBox binding two values

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox

I have a combobox which is populated from a list of names which were obtained from selecting from an Observable collection. However, associated with those names is an ID also in that Observable collection. The goal is when the user selects a new name (Say changes "John" to "Jill") I will be able to obtain the ID, not just the name. The only way I can think of doing this is storing the ID also in the combobox somehow. But I don't know how to do that with binding.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name ">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox  x:Name="namescombo" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.Names}" 
                          SelectedItem="{Binding Name,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="12" Background="White" FontFamily="Cambria" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

C#

```
ObservableCollection<Name> Names = new ObservableCollection<Name>();       
Name twofields = new Name();
        var NamesQuery =
           from p in dataEntities.Names

           select new { p.Name, p.Id };

        foreach (var p in NamesQuery)
        {


            Names.Add(new Name
                {
            ID = p.Id,
            Name = p.Name

                });

        }
 Names = Names.Select(p => p.Name).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: are you using MVVM pattern?

Comment: What is the data type of `DataContext.Names`? Is it an enumeration of strings or an enumeration of `Name` objects?

Comment: Just an enumeration of strings selected from the observable collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ComboBox` contains properties for both the `DisplayMemberPath` and the `SelectedValuePath`, so you could use it to tell the `ComboBox` to identify items by the `"Id"` property, but display the `"Name"` property to the user.

For example,

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name ">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox 
                ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.Names}" 
                DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                SelectedValuePath="Id"
                SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedId}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I would recommend using `SelectedValue` over `SelectedItem` because WPF compares `SelectedItem` by `.Equals()` which defaults to comparing items by reference, and if your `SelectedItem` is not the exact same reference as the item in your `ItemsSource`, it won't get selected.

For example, `SelectedItem = new Person(1, "Test");` would probably not set the selected item correctly, while `SelectedItem = ItemsSource[0]` would since it refers to an item that exists in the `ItemsSource`.

Also, it frequently makes more sense to store just the `Id` of the selected item on a row instead of the entire object :)

Comment: I would disagree here. It might be good in this case. But ideally selected object should always be a part of ItemsSource. (obviously unless comboBox is editable and allow user to enter value)

Comment: @RohitVats I ran into this issue a lot when working with Entity Framework because ComboBox items were obtained by reading a table in the database during one call, while the item being displayed in each row (including the SelectedRecord property obtained from the linked table) was being created during a second database call.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me a lot. I do have one more question. How can I access the SelectedValuePath in my code? Right now, I am currently using DataGrid.CurrentItem to get the rest of the value out, but not sure how to get this one.

Comment: @user3481541 `DataGrid.SelectedItem` it will be the object in the row itself, and you can cast it to the data type of your item and get it's `Id` property. Like this: `((MyItem)DataGrid.SelectedItem).Id`. What do you need this for anyways? Its not normal in WPF to access an item like this from the UI, and there might be a better way of accomplishing the task you're doing with it.

Comment: We have a non normalized table where fID, fName both exist but fID is what is unique. However, the user is not seeing fID and is not changing it, they are only seeing fName and changing that. However, once fName is changed, the fID is what should be updated. I could possibly accomplish the same by joining the table on itself, I suppose. Would that be a better option?

Comment: @user3481541 If you've setup the databindings correctly, this should be done automatically for you. What are you binding your `DataGrid` to? For example, if you bind it an `ObservableCollection<User>` and `User` has a property called `SelectedId`, then the above XAML code would work just fine to automatically update your `User.SelectedId` with the correct `Id` property, even though it displays the `Name` property to the user.

Comment: I think it's working just the way it is. The id is updating with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can **bind directly to Name object collection** and set **[DisplayMemberPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** to **`Name`** property so that strings are shown on GUI but in essence you have complete object binded to comboBox.

This way you can bind **`SelectedItem`** to Name object and can access Id and Name property.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" // Collection of name objects.
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNameObject}"/> // Object of type Name.
```